# Why NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() so slow?

Tags: java, networking

NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() is so slow when many interfaces.

It takes tens of seconds when there are 16 interfaces in Windows 10,
Takes a few minutes when you have 20 interfaces.

Why is it so slow?

Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: @caladeve I using openjdk-1.8.0-212